# Add leading zeros after specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following problem (Example Strings):

10162/0 **should look like** 010162/0000
47000/685 **should look like** 047000/0685
9055/2 **should look like** 009055/0002

So up to the '/', I need 6 digits with leading zeros if there are not exactly 6 digits. And after the '/' I need exactly 4 digits with leading zeros if there are no 4 digits.

I have tried it with:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000/0000' + [column_name], 11) ...
```

but of course, it isn't working cause of the second part after the '/' :)

I hope anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should really be something you handle with your business layer or maybe presentation layer, not in the data layer.

Comment: Or use a trigger/constraint to ensure values are always stored as "nnnnnn/nnnn" format.

Comment: The data is imported from an external source. I don't have the chance to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a bunch of string manipulations.  Something like this:

```
select right(replicate('0', 6) + left(val, charindex('/', val)), 7) +
       right(replicate('0', 4) + right(val, charindex('/', reverse(val)) - 1), 4)
```

Unfortunately, SQL Fiddle just isn't returning this morning, so I can't fully test this.

EDIT: Fixed missing parenthesis